Custom DatePicker: how can I change icon image and open the popup clicking on TextBox on codebehind?
Here's my Custom DatePicker:
<customcontrols:CustomDatePicker x:Name="DataCreazione"
                                 SelectedDate="{Binding DataCreazione, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"
                                 controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Data Creazione"
                                 Cursor="Hand"
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 SelectedDateFormat="Short"
                                 Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                 Grid.Row="1" />

Which I apply this template on code behind:
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Client.customcontrols
{
    public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
    {
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            if (Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", this) is TextBox textbox)
            {
                textbox.IsReadOnly = true;
                textbox.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                textbox.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown_Click;
            }
            if (Template.FindName("PART_Button", this) is Button button)
            {
                button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }

        private void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }
    }
}

I'd like to:

instead of hide the icon, I'd like to change the image of it (using PackIconFontAwesome's CalendarAltSolid), size 16x16, Margin 0,0,8,0
once I click on the textbox, have the same behaviour on clicking on the icon (popup opened, which stay open until I select a date); instead, with PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, it seem it keep popup open until I press left mouse click, once its "up" the popup vanish

Can you help me on this?
EDIT: after mm8 answer, I get the icon "cutted" on the left:

Here's the actual markup:
<customcontrols:CustomDatePicker x:Name="DataCreazione"
                                 SelectedDate="{Binding DataCreazione, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"
                                 controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Data Creazione"
                                 Cursor="Hand"
                                 SelectedDateFormat="Short"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 Margin="20,10,0,0"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                 Grid.Row="1">
    <customcontrols:CustomDatePicker.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate"
                         TargetType="Button">
            <Grid Width="40"
                  Margin="0,0,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <iconPacks:PackIconControl Kind="{x:Static iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesomeKind.CalendarAltSolid}"
                                           Width="16"
                                           Height="16"
                                           Foreground="#81b3d4"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </customcontrols:CustomDatePicker.Resources>
</customcontrols:CustomDatePicker>


You can always define custom template for the Button, e.g.:
<customcontrols:CustomDatePicker x:Name="DataCreazione"
                                 SelectedDate="{Binding DataCreazione, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"
                                 controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Data Creazione"
                                 Cursor="Hand"
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 SelectedDateFormat="Short"
                                 Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                 Grid.Row="1">
    <customcontrols:CustomDatePicker.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
            <Grid Background="White">
                <iconPacks:PackIconControl Kind="{x:Static iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesomeKind.CalendarAltSolid}"
                                           Width="16"
                                           Height="16"
                                           Foreground="#81b3d4"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </customcontrols:CustomDatePicker.Resources>
</customcontrols:CustomDatePicker>


if (Template.FindName("PART_Button", this) is Button button)
{
    button.Template = FindResource("ButtonTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
}

As for your other requirement, I think it should work if you handle the MouseLeftButtonUp event and set the Focusable property of the control to false:
if (Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", this) is TextBox textbox)
{
    textbox.IsReadOnly = true;
    textbox.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

    Focusable = false;
    textbox.MouseLeftButtonUp += (e, s) => IsDropDownOpen = true;
}


For the first part: it cut the icon. Added to the answer the whole markup, uhm it seems correct? :O

Unclear why you're using HorizontalAlignment and Margin. See my edited suggestion. Does it still cut?

no, but I want to place 10 (margin) from right. With your example its at fixed position, if I place margin it start to cut again.

Its ok for now, thanks! All works perfect!
